# How to use rxjava2 with MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, multiautocompletetextview, rx-binding

I checked support of Rxbinding for MultiAutoCompleteTextView. But haven't seen any option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need RxBindings (it helps but is not necessary) to get any view to work, you could 'bind' a view by yourself, it means that you could use RxJava to do async work but handle data and bind it to your prefered View by yourself.